# printing drupal field in comment.tpl.php

Tags: entities

I have disabled user pictures, and created a field in users instead because i feel i have more control of the user pictures, i.e. i can organize them on webhotel with tokens, and choose a certain picture style etc.

Now i want to use the field in the comment.tpl.php of the theme, so i printed following code `<?php echo render($content['field_profilbillede']); ?>` where the `<?php print $picture ?>` usually appear .. but nothing happends at all .. what did i do wrong?

Ps. i got the code from another post on stackoverflow.com so yes i have already searched for related posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive about this, but maybe try removing the `$content` portion and rendering the field directly?

`<?php echo render($field_profilbillede); ?>`